# Do the party skills of my companions add up?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

When leveling up my companions I wonder how much influence their skill values have.

*Personal skill* seems clear enough that it only concerns the actual companion. Yet *Party skills* have me confused.

For instance, when building advancement or besieging a castle only the companion with the highest *Engineer* skill counts. So it seems ill-advised to waste points for other companion here. Same seems to be the case for *Trade*.

But is it also the case with e.g. *Trainer*, *Wound Treatment*, *Surgery*, and *First Aid*?

Will those benefits add up, as in will two companions with high a *Trainer* skill teach recruits faster, or does again only the one with the highest value count?

Answer (score 6):

As per the [Mount & Blade wikia](http://mountandblade.wikia.com/wiki/Skills):

## Personal skills

Personal skills are granted only the individual character.

- Power Strike
- Power Throw
- Power Draw
- Weapon Master
- Shield
- Ironflesh
- Athletics
- Riding
- Horse Archery
- Trainer (*)
- Persuasion

(*) Trainer is a notable exception in that it stacks. Trainer grants the experience to *all* (valid) party members, but as a personal skill it belongs only to the character who learned it. Multiple characters with Trainer therefore accumulate a higher experience gain.

## Leader skills

Leader skills are granted to the entire party, but only the party leader's skill value is used.

- Inventory Management
- Prisoner Management
- Leadership

## Party skills

Party skills work like leader skills, except that the highest level *any* party member has is used. In addition to this, there is a bonus awarded if there are multiple characters with the same party skill in one party. (That is, both the player and at least one companion exceed level 2 in the particular skill) In that case the highest level is used and the following bonus applied for the second highest skill level:

```
0 - 1 = +0
2 - 4 = +1
5 - 7 = +2
8 - 9 = +3
10    = +4
```

- Looting
- Tracking
- Tactics
- Path-finding
- Spotting
- Wound Treatment
- Surgery
- First Aid
- Engineer
- Trade

Answer (score -3):

I think only the member with the highest skill adds up to that specific skill. Because the only member who adds to the Path-finding skill is the one with the highest, and I've (not knowing this) given all my members Path-finding skill points.

Comment: This doesn't realy add anything to the existing answer. Also you seem to assume that all the skills work like Path-finding, while the other answer goes to great lenght to detail how different skills work differently.